# Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop, can't open terminal

Tags: command-line, login

I have Ubuntu 18.04 installed on my computer.
now i can't login to my account. when I enter my password, screen turns black for a second and returns into login page again.
I saw many issues about Ubuntu login loop, but they all solved using terminal commands. I can't open a terminal here. I tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> but noting happens.
Can anyone help?

Comment: I'm assuming you have tried other tty's (terminals); you could also try another keyboard (*I had a strange microsoft branded keyboard where those keystrokes wouldn't work as it sent some unusual keystrokes to the system where combinations of keys were used), or `ssh` into your system (which will only work if you've installed `openssh-server` & enabled remote login).

Comment: Have you tried booting to runlevel 3 (i.e. without graphics)?